# R leaflet addWMStiles with projection

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

I'm trying to follow this example: https://rpubs.com/cyclemumner/228100, especially the part where wms tiles with custum projection are added, but when I run the code I don't seem to get the wms tiles.
I've installed leaflet from github.

```
if (!require('devtools')) install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')
```

Using leaflet 1.0.2.9010,R R-3.3.2 and RStudio 1.0.136.

The code I run is the following

```
library(leaflet)

zoom <- 1
maxZoom <- 5

crsAntartica <-  leafletCRS(
  crsClass = 'L.Proj.CRS',
  code = 'EPSG:3031',
  proj4def = '+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs',
  resolutions = c(8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256),
  origin = c(-4194304, 4194304),
  bounds =  list( c(-4194304, -4194304), c(4194304, 4194304) )
)

leaflet(options= leafletOptions(crs=crsAntartica, minZoom = zoom, maxZoom=maxZoom, worldCopyJump = FALSE)) %>%
  setView(0, -90, 0) %>%
  addWMSTiles(baseUrl="https://maps.environments.aq/mapcache/antarc/?",
              layers="antarc_ramp_bath_shade_mask",
              options=WMSTileOptions(format="image/png",transparent=TRUE),
              attribution="xxx") %>%
  addGraticule()
```

What I get is this

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason why I didn't get it to work. The wms tiles don't show up when viewed in the RStudio viewer. When I put the code inside a shiny app i'm working on then the wms tiles appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **RStudio**: I just had the same issue and found a simple solution to see everything. Just use "show in new window":

[image]

Using some random data it looks the following:

[image]